# Directly using keymapping inside a function

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode

So, I'm usually used to making (decently) complex mapping, and sometimes, I'd like to run mapping on very specific conditions. Let's take for example a simple premise:

```
first line
second ...
long text from here
```

Say we want to make a mapping that select (in visual mode) one line at a time, (eg: select first line, then select the second one separately, etc)
When I say select here, I do mean the full line (until end of line on the current line)

Anyway, here the example mapping for this:

```
nnoremap x <ESC><Down>^v$
```

This works fine, except for the first line. To fix this, there is a number of ways, but since this is just a *simple example* to explain what I mean, let's just check if we're on the first line or not in a function:

```
function! Visual_cycle_line()
if line('.') == 1
  "call feedkeys('<ESC>') cannot be called here since it wouldn't execute right in terminal vim?? (ends up putting us in insert mode somehow)
  call feedkeys('^v$')
else
  "call feedkeys('<ESC>') same as above
  call feedkeys('<Down>^v$')
endif
```

As shown above, it works fine *except* for the fact that, the part where it is supposed to *escape* visual mode, in which using `<ESC>` specifically with `feedkeys` doesn't work as intended (AFAIK).

I also tried to use `normal!` but it doesn't seems to work with the above set up either.

Now back to my initial question: How can I use keymapping grammar *directly* inside any vim function, *without* having to care about formatting, or taking into account specific key weird behavior (eg: like with the example with  and such) just as if I was defining a mapping with `noremap` and the like?

To give some more perspective, I want to do what I explained inside functions, the same way we can use regex there (eg: doing `:regexhere` in an if blocks works fine in both functions and commandline).

P.S.: I'm also aware of the possibility of just setting up mapping inside functions using `noremap` and the like, instead of running the actual keymapping themselves, but that *only* work in certain workflows, which depends on the needs/preferences, which is why I still want to do/or at least know this anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I understand your end goal (XY problem?)

But if your end goal to have something like this:

[image]

Then 2 mappings for `x` would look like:

```
nnoremap x V
xnoremap x <ESC>jV
```

As `feedkeys()`, you have to use doublequotes and escape for special keys:

```
function! Visual_cycle_line()
    if line('.') == 1
      call feedkeys("\<ESC>")
      call feedkeys('^v$')
    else
      call feedkeys("\<ESC>")
      call feedkeys("\<Down>^v$")
    endif
endfunc
```

Although I doubt that function would work as you think it should anyway (granted you only map `x` in normal mode).

Comment: Thank you, this works. Btw, this might sounds like an excuse but this isn't an XY problem, as this was just a well suited example, at least to me at the time (if I showed all the other way I would solve it, it wouldn't count as an example right?)

Comment: also, another minor explanation: in case you were curious, using `V` in visual mode, does work better than just doing `^v$` but there a slight misrepresentation of the offsets from `:echo getpos(''>')` where one of the offset will be `2147483647` or so when doing `V`...which is why I've been using `^v$` instead for my own purpose, but that's beside the point